# How to read line-by-line of a single parameter (input) from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, string, input, parameters

I'm working on a [Racker Rank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop/problem) whose function in JavaScript receives a single parameter (input).

Input Format:
The first line contains an integer,  (the number of test cases). 
Each line  of the  subsequent lines contain a String.

I need to print the even-indexed and odd-indexed characters of each string (S) separated by a space on a single line (see the Sample below for more detail).

```
2
Hacker
Rank
```

```
Hce akr
Rn ak
```

Is there a way to read the input line-by-line and save each string in a specific variable? If I achieve that I know how to solve the problem by iterating through the string. Otherwise, I'm lost. If not, how else could I handle the input? Thanks!

Readline doesn't seem to be the way to go.

```
function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here

} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);
});
```

What I have tried without success:

```
function processData(input) {

    let myArray = input.split("\n"); 

    let even_indexed = "";
    let odd_indexed = "";

    for (let i = 1; i <= myArray.length; i++) {
        let str = myArray[i];
        let len = str.length;

        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++){
            if (j % 2 == 0) { //check if the index is even;
                even_indexed.concat(str[j]);
            }
            else {
                odd_indexed.concat(str[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("%s  %s", even_indexed, odd_indexed);
}
```

Comment: I thought Hackerrank automatically parsed the base text input into usable parameters for you, at least with Javascript challenges? (Their instructions are misleading, at least in the few challenges I've done.) Can you post the link? Manually messing with `process.stdin` shouldn't be necessary

Comment: If you are indeed doing a challenge, it's probably a good idea to declare that upfront. Otherwise, you'll get people suggesting, for instance, that sending an object with three properties to your function would be more clean.

Comment: Hackerrank doesn't process my output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use **split()** method with a newline operator?

```html
<script>
let x= `Hey
I'm
a
multiline
string`

console.log(x.split("\n"))
</script>
```

The result will be an array on which every element represents a line of your input.

Answer (score 0):

I made this pretty quickly so I apologize for it being kinda messy and I know there are probably more efficient ways of doing this, but it does what you are asking for.

```js
let input = `This
is
a
multiline
string`

let splitWords = [];
input.split(/\r?\n/).forEach(function(e){ // Split the array by \n (newline) and/or \r (carriage return)
  currentLine = {evenIndex: [], oddIndex: []}
  for(let i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    if((i + 1)%2 === 0){
      currentLine.evenIndex.push(e[i]);
    }
    else{
      currentLine.oddIndex.push(e[i]);
    }
  }
  splitWords.push(currentLine);
});
splitWords.forEach(function(e){
  console.log(e.oddIndex.join('') + " " + e.evenIndex.join(''))
});
```

Comment: Well you have to remove the first line if you don't want it. I didn't include that because it's a pretty simple change.